# .NET 7 minimal API request timeout

Tags: asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I found this in .NET 8 (prerelease) but I can't use it due to company policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-7.0

May I know how can I do the same in .NET core 7?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v8.0.0-preview.3.23177.8.

[image]

And find `RequestTimeouts` is the new feature in .NET 8. Currently not compatible with .NET 7 and cannot be used directly in .NET 7. If we need to achieve similar functions, we need to write custom middleware.

[image]